# Paypal Node SDK payment.execute http req - Maintaining State with multiple ec2 instances on elastic load balancing. Description?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, paypal, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am about to go live with a MEAN app onto an elastic beanstalk cloud with multiple ec2 instances so I have a problem:

At the moment, I am selling tickets to events using paypal node SDK. I do my payment.create and I pass this transaction object:

```
transactions: [{
    amount:{
    total: req.headers.amount,
    currency:'AUD'
    },
    description:'eventID: ' + req.headers.eventid + ', userID: ' + req.headers.userid
}]
```

I create an associative array within my server to cache the eventid and the userid, and I used the paypal transaction ID as the key so that when paypal returns with confirmation that payment was successful I know which user and which event I need to update in my database.

If I go to cloud, if the HTTP redirect comes to a different ec2 instance this method will fail, because that associative array will be on a different machine. The ideal solution to this would be to be able to pass the eventid and userid to paypal and have them pass it back to me, is there a way to access the transaction/description data in their req callback or is there another good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Either [enable sticky sessions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html) in the load balancer, or start storing that data somewhere like a [Redis cache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/) that all the servers share.

Comment: Ya I was looking at sticky sessions, but I figured it would be super easy if I could just pass the two strings along to paypal and have them pass it back to me. I'm not sure if somewhere in the req they send back to me the description string I sent to them is buried.

Comment: Also, its paypals confirmation server that is sending back the redirect after confirmation, so it is not the same user making the http request, its a http post coming in from paypal which wouldnt help with sticky sessions right?

Comment: I haven't had to use the Paypal API in a few years, but last time I used it Paypal caused the user's browser to redirect. It wasn't doing a direct HTTP post. If that's the case then sticky sessions wouldn't work. You mentioned in your original question it's a "HTTP redirect" not a direct post from Paypal. If it is a redirect then sticky sessions would work.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping to use the paypal.payment description string to access these but I found a simple solution which suits my purposes, I pass the two strings into the paypal return_url and then use then with req.query.e and req.query.u when the return occurs:

```
redirect_urls: {
            return_url: config.baseUrl + '/pay/payment?e='+req.headers.eventid+'&u='+req.headers.userid, 
            cancel_url: config.baseUrl + '/'
        },
```